# What is the appropriate nav config for autonomous frontier_exploration?

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot that can successfully localize, navigate and reach goals submitted to the move_base package within the ROS Navigation stack. It's using ROS Hydro with Ubuntu 12.04 running on dual-core 1.6 GHz Intel Atom netbook, AMCL and a static map (previously created using teleop/gmapping). Now I would like to use frontier_exploration to have the robot explore autonomously. Actually, I would like it to explore completely unknown space and use gmapping to create a new static map as it explores (not utilizing a previously generated map). I believe this is a supported use case for the frontier_exploration package. Could someone confirm that?

On reading the documentation, I see that there are two options:

1. without global map
2. with global map

Regarding the global map: is that a reference to the move_base global costmap, a gmapping map, or a static map on the map server, or other? My impression is it could be any of those (but it's not clear). Is it correct?

What is the purpose of frontier_exploration if you already have a global map? If someone would explain that, it would help my understanding. However, as already stated, exploring with a pre-built static global map is not my objective here.

In setting up navigation to work with frontier_exploration, I'm faced with the issue of how to configure the navigation stack itself. I think I want to use option #1 above (unless option #2 refers to a map created on-the-fly by gmapping?), which leads me to believe I do not want to load a global map in the navigation launch file. Therefore, I would omit the following (from the move_base node launch):

```
<rosparam file="$(find hexapod_2dnav)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
<rosparam file="$(find hexapod_2dnav)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
```

Beyond that, for my above described use case, I should remove the launch of AMCL and substitute it with the launch of gmapping?

Is the above correct?

Thanks very much for any advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196254/what-is-the-appropriate-nav-config-for-autonomous-frontier_exploration?/) by [jordan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20512/jordan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-07**:
Hi, i was wondering if you could get the frontier_exploration work for you? i got a tiny little problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Option #2 DOES include creating a global map on the fly with gmapping. Sorry for the confusion, I'm going to have to think about how to reword that documentation to make everything clearer. In essence, `global_map.launch` is for when you have a /map topic, and `no_global_map.launch` is for when you don't.

Yes, you should omit AMCL and use gmapping. They both provide the very important `/map->/odom` transform.

`global_map.launch` should work relatively out of the box for you, just substitute the proper sensor and robot configuration, mirroring your `move_base` setup.

> What is the purpose of frontier_exploration if you already have a global map

My original use case was actually to explore a known map and search for a person.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-07**:
Hi @paulbovbel sorry for directly bugging you here, i have an Issue with frontier_exploration package and pretty much read most of the available online resource. could you please check my [Question](http://answers.ros.org/question/208702/problem-with-frontier_exploration-pkg/) here. Thanks so much!

**Comment by [RS](https://answers.ros.org/users/22821/rs/) on 2015-07-26**:
I'm sorry but I don't understand by what you mean when you say no map topic?Explored data needs to be published on some topic right?